# Titleview not visible on IOS - Maui

Tags: ios, xaml, maui, titlebar

I'm using Maui to create a cross-platform app. To navigate through the app the appshell is used. On Android everything is working fine, but on IOS the custom titleview isn't displayed right. After startup only the bottom half of the view is visible, and after I switch to a different tab and back, the titleview is gone completely. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there any way to fix this?

(Maybe related to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/12834 but I'm not sure)

xaml:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
       <Grid>
            -- content --
       </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be reproduced for iOS. Several issues on Github has mentioned this question: [Shell TitleView disappearing on tab change #9687](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9687) and [Title view not displayed after navigating shell tabs #9269](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9269).

Also, several workaround has been found, such as [wrapping the shell in a navigation page](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9269#issuecomment-1284647256) and [using a custom render for AppShell on iOS](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9687#issuecomment-1310566378).

Seems so many issues are related to the commit you mentioned in the question. You could wait for the new release, update Visual Studio and reopen these issues if it still not work.

Hope it works for you.